# generate a war file using Powershell

Tags: powershell, file, war

I am new to Powershell.I am trying to generate a war file in the location of jar.exe , any inputs highly appreciated.

I have tried to generate the war file using Start Process, But it is not generating the war file

$wargen=Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/K cd /d D:\Temp\ws\9.0\base\java\8.0\bin\jar.exe -cvf foo.war" -Verb "runas" -Verbose

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to try so hard. It's not necessary to invoke `Start-Process` or `cmd.exe` to run a command. PowerShell is a shell; it can run commands. Just type the command at the PowerShell prompt and press `Enter`.

```
PS C:\> D:\Temp\ws\9.0\base\java\8.0\bin\jar.exe -cvf foo.war
```

I am wondering about why your example uses the `runas` shell verb to run the command as an elevated process; my guess is that this is unnecessary.

Comment: Hi @Bill_Stewart thanks for the quick reply it was part of automation script and its functionality is to generate a war file using powershell script hence i had to use Start-Process .

Comment: You do not need to use `Start-Process` to run a program in PowerShell. In particular, you especially don't want to use the `Start-Process` with `runas` when you are trying to automate, because the elevation prompt will block the process.